# SVN Repository Change

Tags: tortoisesvn

My svn repository address is changed `'X'` to `'Y'`. so for this i changed my build script accordingly.but when i m going for to update my local workarea location it's showing the ERROR that can't connect to svn URL and it's showing Previous URL means `'X'`. how can i get it out from this error. pls help me out. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you must use relocate to switch your working copy to new URL

http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-relocate.html

Answer (score 0):

TortoiseSVN has a [manual chapter](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-relocate.html) about this. Without Tortoise you usually do the following from command line:

```
svn switch --relocate X Y WORKPATH
```

Comment: i m using cmd propmpt n run this cmd `svn switch --relocate X Y` and then `svn update`but it's showing ERROR `Can't connect to host 'X': No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

Comment: @picnic4u: You also need to specify path to your working copy as a third argument. Updated description.

Comment: thanks buddy it's resoved throught the realocate option of repository